# How to have a toggle all checkbox in svelte

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to set up a list of checkboxes and a button which allows toggling all the buttons, my code below:

```
<script>
  const items = ["a", "b", "c"]
  let selected = [];

  function toggleAll() {
    if (selected.length === 0) {
      selected = [...items]
    } else {
      selected = [];
    }
  }
</script>

<div>
    {selected.length} Selected
    <div>
        <input 
            type="checkbox" 
            on:click|preventDefault={toggleAll} 
            checked={selected.length === items.length}
        />
        <strong>All</strong>
    </div>
    {#each items as item}
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" bind:group={selected} name={item} value={item}  />
            {item}
        </div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

This has some weird behaviour, if I click the all checkbox all the items are checked but not the all checkbox, but if I click each item without pressing the all checkbox it then is checked.

I think the preventDefault is doing something, because if I remove that the all works as expected, but then checking 1 item, then checking the all checkbox leaves the all checked and none of the items.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the `change` event and the current DOM `checked` state to toggle:

```html
<input 
    type="checkbox" 
    on:change={toggleAll} 
    checked={selected.length === items.length} />
```

```js
function toggleAll(e) {
    selected = e.target.checked ? [...items] : [];
}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/986adbafc5b042cbbf979c1381c7cacc?version=3.50.1)

Btw, you should use `label` elements to label form inputs.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `preventDefault` has no effect but it's the logic inside `toggleAll` - selecting all is the priority?
If the 'master' checkbox is clicked when not all other checkboxes are checked -> select all.
If all are checked -> deselect all.
[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e54cf61806b0474a803769daaeb12f1b?version=3.50.1)

```
<script>
    const items = ["a", "b", "c"]
    let selected = [];
    $: allSelected = items.length === selected.length

    function toggleAll() {
        if (allSelected) {
            selected = [];
        } else {
            selected = [...items]
        }
    }
</script>

<div>
    {selected.length} Selected
    <div>
        <input 
                     type="checkbox" 
                     on:click={toggleAll} 
                     checked={allSelected}
                     />
        <strong>All</strong>
    </div>
    {#each items as item}
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" bind:group={selected} name={item} value={item}  />
        {item}
    </div>
    {/each}
</div>
```